# How convert Digit in ASCII

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to store in memory a value that is in a register, but I need to store it in ASCII code. This value can be from 0 to 256, so the length of the ASCII string is variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to divide your value by 10. Remainder plus 0x30 (ASCII code of the symbol '0') is last symbol of your resulting string. Then you do the same to the quotient (divide by 10 and add 0x30 to remainder) in order to get the symbol before last, and so on.
P.S. Of course this is true only if you need a decimal representation of your value.